# could i authorize some person to use the menu in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I just create a menu in my spreadsheet and I want to add a list of user who could use this menu. I just wonder whether I could use some methods like addEditors(emailAddress) or some others methods to achieve this?
Here is the code I write

```
function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Add new row', 'addNewRow')  //Add "Add row" function to Custom menu
      .addItem('Delete last row', 'deleteLastRow') //Add "Generate invoice" function to Custom menu
      .addToUi();
}
```

currently I want to grant some user like "me@gst.org.us" and "you@gst.org.us" to use this methods, others cannot.

Could I please ask how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is a way of doing that by just scripting alone. Try developing an [Apps Script Add-ons for Sheets, Docs, Slides and Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/). Then, check the [Add-on Authorization Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle) and
[Publishing Add-ons for Domain-Wide Installation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide) to learn about access and authorization.

You can also check [Apps Script web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) as it has options who can have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to add this check to both the `addNewRow()` and `deleteLastRow()`:

```
if (checkUser()) {
    //Add or delete row
}
else return;
```

where the checkUser function looks like:

```
function checkUser() {
    var okUsers = ["me@gst.org.us","you@gst.org.us"];
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    for (var u in okUsers) if (user == okUsers[u]) return true;
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Your email is not authorized to use this function.");
    return false;
}
```

If the person trying to use the function is not in your okUsers array, checkUser() evaluates to false, and the user will be alerted that they are not authorized. I think you could also get rid of the for loop by using:

```
if (okUsers.includes(user)) return true;
```

but I haven't tried using the `Array.includes()` method with Google scripts before, so not sure if that is supported.
I also didn't get a chance to test this code, but it should work. Let me know if you run into any problems.